# Forward procedure with BIC

Tags: r

I'm trying to select variables for a linear model with forward stepwise algorithm and BIC criterion. As the help file indicates and as I always did, I wrote the following:

```
model.forward<-lm(y~1,data=donnees)
model.forward.BIC<-step(model.forward,direction="forward", k=log(n), scope=list(lower = ~1, upper = ~x1+x2+x3), data=donnees)
```

with `k=log(n)` indicating I'm using BIC. But R returns:

```
Error in extractAIC.lm(fit, scale, k = k, ...) : object 'n' not found
```

I never really asked myself the question before but I think that `n` is supposed to be defined in function `step`(it s the number of variables in the model at each iteration).... Anyway, the issue never happened to me before! Restarting R doesn't change anything and I admit I have no idea of what can cause this error.

Here is some code to test:

```
y<-runif(20,0,10)
x1<-runif(20,0,1)
x2<-y+runif(20,0,5)
x3<-runif(20,0,1)-runif(20,0,1)*y
donnees<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
step(model.forward,direction="forward", 
         k=log(nrow(donnees)), scope=list(lower = ~1, upper = ~x1+x2+x3), 
         data=donnees)
```

or more generally ...

```
... k=log(nobs(model.forward)) ...
```

(for example, if there are `NA` values in your data, then `nobs(model.forward)` will be different from `nrow(donnees)`.  On the other hand, if you have `NA` values in your *predictors*, you're going to run into trouble when doing model selection anyway.)

Comment: Err, you made me realize I was wrong about n's meaning... I thought it was the number of variables in the model but i got mixed up with REML mixed models' estimation. So you're right, thank you very much ! I still wonder why n doesn't works while it used too though.